# Vagrant for web server with shared folders: Apache breaks file permissions if it tries to stat a file before it exists

Tags: apache, vagrant

I'm not sure if this is an issue with vagrant, virtualbox or a configuration issue inside the box itsef, however:

Using the following setup: Apache is running in the guest with its server root set to /srv/http, this is a synched folder which points to ./public_html on the host.

While most of the time it works as expected, the following steps causes an issue

1) Navigate to a file that doesn't exist localhost:8080/test2.css -- shows a 404 error as expected but correctly connects to the guest which is serving the error

2) Create test2.css with some content and place it in public_html

3) Reload localhost:8080/test2.css -- Still shows a 404 error even though the file now exists

4) To debug, run vagrant ssh and then ls /srv/http. Which shows:

    `ls: cannot access test2.css: No such file or directory`

So it's seeing the file, sort of but it shows without any permissions:

    `-????????? ? ?          ?            ? test2.css
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant    7 Oct 23 11:13 test3.css`

If I then re-save the file as test3.css, a file that hasn't yet been accessed it works perfectly. E.g. on the host, save the file I had open as test3.css and then navigate to it, it works as expected!

Any ideas? On why this might be?

In short: If apache has tried to read a file that doesn't exist, creating that file will then cause it to have invalid permissions. If apache has never tried to read the file before, it can be created and work as expected.

Thanks for any help, I'm really confused by this!

Comment: You could see if turning off `sendfile()` in Apache helps, you can use the EnableSendfile off directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a kernel bug on the guest. Upgrading to 4.2.4 using the same Vagrant/Virtualbox/Guest Modules solved the issue.